# Count number of remaining results with Solr

Tags: search, solr, filter

I have a Database with Cars and i want to create filters to lets users search for them quicker. I've worked with Solr before but i've never used facets.

The filters should work like this:

- Brands

  - BMW (4)
  - VW (5)
  - Toyota (6)
- Colors

  - Red (4)
  - Blue (3)
  - Yellow (2)
  - Green (3)
  - White (3)
- Types

  - Sports (5)
  - Sedan (10)

If the user selects one it should end up like this:

- Brands

  - BMW (1)
  - VW (2)
  - Toyota (1)
- Colors

  - **Red** (4) <-- Selected
  - Blue (-)
  - Yellow (-)
  - Green (-)
  - White (-)
- Types

  - Sports (1)
  - Sedan (3)

What would be the best way to archive something like this with Solr. Would Facets be perfect for this? I did some research but i haven't found any documentation displaying this kind of feature. Is there a name for this kind of filtering? Thanks allot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using Solr facets you can achieve this.
Give field name to `facets.field`

Index your documents into Solr. you can refer some links as [this](http://blog.comperiosearch.com/blog/2014/08/28/indexing-database-using-solr/) to index your db data into Solr. after indexing, query along with facets component.

Example:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json&facet=true&facet.field=cat
```

scroll down to see facets results as below.

```
"facet_fields":{
      "cat":[
        "book",17,
        "electronics",12,
        "paperback",6,
        "currency",4,
        "memory",3,
        "connector",2,
        "graphics card",2,
        "hard drive",2,
        "search",2,
```

Comment: So facets are counting by default? Must have missed that. Thanks allot! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yes. facet.field will help  you. upvote or accept my answer if you find it usefull. thank you.

Comment: You've pointed me into the right direction. But i somehow fail to get more then one category to display. Can you show me an example how to make this work with 2 or more categories depending each other? Like i have in my example.

Comment: I just figured it out! You have to put additional fields into the string as additional variables. It works great! Thanks allot for your help.

Comment: Add multiple parameters `facet.field`.  in your case it might be like `facet.field=Brands&facet.field=Colors&facet.field=Types`